# Convert integer to array

Tags: c++, arrays, integer

I would like to convert an integer into an array, so that it looks like the following:

```
int number = 123456 ;
int array[7] ;
```

with the result:

```
array[0] = 1 
array[1] = 2
...
array[6] = 6
```

Comment: It's homework, but I'll bite. My wife didn't really understand this one until I explained it to her.

Comment: Something goes wrong in your "...". There are 7 members of the array, but only 6 decimal digits in the number.

Answer (score 30):

Perhaps a better solution is to work backwards:

`123456 % 10 = 6`

`123456 / 10 = 12345`

`12345 % 10 = 5`

`12345 / 10 = 1234`

Answer (score 18):

just use modular arithmetic:

```
int array[6];
int number = 123456;
for (int i = 5; i >= 0; i--) {
    array[i] = number % 10;
    number /= 10;
}
```

Comment: how about an answer which actually explains the approach so the OP *learns* something?

Comment: That will only work properly on 6 digit non-negative integers.

Comment: I wanted the OP to think about how to extend it to handle other numbers, without just giving the general case.

Answer (score 7):

Here what I came up with, the integerToArray function returns a vector that is converted from the integer value. you can test it with the main function as well:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector <int> integerToArray(int x)
{
    vector <int> resultArray;
    while (true)
    {
    resultArray.insert(resultArray.begin(), x%10);
    x /= 10;
    if(x == 0)
        return resultArray;
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector <int> temp = integerToArray(1234567);
    for (auto const &element : temp)
        cout << element << " " ;
    return 0;
}

//outputs 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Answer (score 6):

You can extract the last digit of the number this way:

```
int digit = number % 10;
number /= 10;
```

Note that you should also check whether `number` is positive. Other values require additional handling.

Comment: are these two different ways to do the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

Take the log10 of the number to get the number of digits. Put that in, say `pos`, then, in a loop, take the modulo of 10 (`n % 10`), put the result in the array at position `pos`. Decrement `pos` and divide the number by 10. Repeat until `pos == 0`

What did you want to do with the sign if it's negative?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>    

std::vector<int> vec;
for (int i = log10(input); i >= 0; i--)
{
  vec.push_back(input / int(std::pow(10, i)) % 10);
}
```

Might be a good approach, I think

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can imagine now is:

```
char array[40];
int number = 123456;

memset(array, 0x00, sizeof(array));

sprintf(array, "%d", number);
```

Additionally you can convert each digit to int just subtracting the char value by 0x30.

**EDIT**: If this is a homework, your teacher you probably ask you to write the program using % operator though (example 12 % 10 = 2). If this is the case, good homework ;-)

Comment: that's a char array, not an int array

Comment: If you're going to use sprintf, please at least use snprintf

Comment: I know its a char array, but you can easily convert to int subtracting the char value by 0x30, as I observed in the answer. snprintf is not C standard.

Comment: @Andres - snprintf is std C99, will be included in C++/1x and is available now on most C++ compilers as a common extension

Comment: Great, good to know @Phil. I said that because I tried to use it in some projects in Unix, but the compiler we were using didn't had the support.

Answer (score 0):

You can use modulus to determine the last digit.

And you can use division to move another digit to the last digit's place.

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply "convert" it. The integer is not represented in software in decimal notation. So the individual digits you want *don't* exist. They have to be computed.

So, given an arbitrary number, how can you determine the number of ones?

We could divide by ten, and then take the remainder: For 123, the division would give 12, and then there's a remainder of 3. So we have 3 ones. The 12 tells us what we have past the ones, so it can be our input for the next iteration. We take that, divide by 10, and get 1, and a remainder of 2. So we have 2 in the tens place, and 1 left to work with for the hundreds. Divide that by 10, which gives us zero, and a remainder of 1. So we get 1 in the hundreds place, 2 in the tens place, and 3 in the ones place. And we're done, as the last division returned zero.

Answer (score 0):

See SO question [Language showdown: Convert string of digits to array of integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166899/language-showdown-convert-string-of-digits-to-array-of-integers/167547#167547) for a C/C++ version (as well as other languages).

Answer (score 0):

if this is really homework then show it your teacher - just for fun ;-)

CAUTION! very poor performance, clumsy way to reach the effect you expect and generally don't do this at home(work) ;-)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector< int > ints_t;

struct digit2int
{
    int operator()( const char chr ) const
    {
        const int result = chr - '0';
        return result;
    }
};

void foo( const int number, ints_t* result )
{
    std::ostringstream os;
    os << number;
    const std::string& numberStr = os.str();
    std::transform(
        numberStr.begin(),
        numberStr.end(),
        std::back_inserter( *result ),
        digit2int() );
}

int main()
{
    ints_t array;
    foo( 123456, &array );
    std::copy(
        array.begin(),
        array.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator< int >( std::cout, "\n" ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to turn it into a string then it would be really easy, just do what everyone else is saying about using the % operator:

Let's say num = 123, we can do this:

```
string str;
while (num > 0)
{
   str = (num % 10) + str;  //put last digit and put it into the beginning of the string
   num = num /10;  //strip out the last digit
}
```

Now you can use str as an array of chars.  Doing this with an array is a hassle because putting things in the beginning of an array requires you to shift everything else.  What we can do is, instead of putting each digit into a string, we can put it into a stack.  It will put it in a backwards order like this: 3 2 1.  Then we can pop off the top number one by one and put that into an array in the correct order.  You array will look like this: 1 2 3.  I will leave the implementation to you since this is homework.

@Broam has a good solution, but like he stated,  it's for working backwards.  I think the OP or whoever comes looking into this thread will want it forwards and that's why I'm posting this.  If you have a better solution, please reply, I'm interested as well.

Answer (score 0):

To convert an integer to array, you can do the steps below:

- Get the total number of digits in a number to which we want to convert to
  array.For this purpose, we will use `count_digits()` function which will return total no of digits after ignoring leading zeros.

> 

```
digits = count_digits(n);
```

- Now we will dynamically allocate memory for our resulting array, just like

> 

```
int* arr = new int[count_digits(n)]
```

- After allocating memory, we will populate the array using the for loop below

> 

```
int digits = count_digits(num);
for (int i = digits; i > 0; i--){
    arr[i-1] = num % 10;
    num = num / 10;
}
```

After performing the steps above, we will be able to convert an integer to array. Remember, `num` is the number that we want to convert into array and `digits` is the variable which gives us the number of digits in a given number ignoring leading zeros.