# splitting a number and storing in int array

Tags: c++

Is there a way to split a number and store digits in an int array?

I am looking for a way to remove some digits from a number (for a divisible algorithm proof).

for example, if I have a number 12345, I need to perform this operation:

1234 - 5 = 1229

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `int n = 12345; int diff = n / 10 - n % 10; cout << diff;`

Comment: Do you mean that you want each base ten digit in on spot of an array

Comment: Terminology issue - you're looking to take digits from an integer number, not to take integers from a number (though I guess digits are integers too).

Comment: Well, now that I read the assignment again, there is no need. What if I needed to do that? without knowing the length of the number..?

Comment: @Krzysiek `vector<int> v; while(n) { v.push_back(n % 10); n /= 10; }`

Comment: To get all the digits, you repeatedly apply the answer Yang gave, each time extracting an extra digit from what's left. When what's left is zero, you're finished. If you store in a `vector<char>`, you don't need to know how many digits in advance. As an optimisation, you may prefer to append in reverse order (that's the order you extract them), then reverse the whole vector. There may be some `<algorithms>` library trickery to get the same effect, but I doubt there's a function that does this in one step. Personally, I'd just write the loop.

Comment: Actually, one thing worth mentioning is `stringstream`. You can effectively "print" the number into a `stringstream` instance, then extract the result as a `string` (which is very similar to a `vector<char>`, of course). Using a `stringstream` is a lot like using `cout`, except the "output" is stored in memory.

Comment: @Steve314 Please, for the love of God, don't suggest using strings to solve a math problem!

Comment: @H2CO3 - I'm not Christian so it's OK. Anyway, must go - this goat isn't going to sacrifice itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `n % 10` to get the last digit and `n / 10` to get the others. For example, 5=12345%10, 1234=12345/10.

[Convert integer to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860983/convert-integer-to-array):

```
int array[6];
int n = 123456;
for (int i = 5; i >= 0; i--) {
    array[i] = n % 10;
    n /= 10;
}
```

In general, `vector`s are preferred in C++, especially in this case since you probably don't know in advance the number of digits.

```
int n = 123456;
vector<int> v;
for(; n; n/=10)
  v.push_back( n%10 );
```

Then `v` contains `{6,5,4,3,2,1}`. You may optionally use [`std::reverse`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/) to reverse it.

Comment: You should prefer std::vector over arrays, especially in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to give you an answer in sudo code.

```
int [] makeArrayFromInt (int input){
    arr = new int [floor(log(input)/log(10)) + 1]
    int index = 0
    while(input>0){
        arr[index]=input%10
        input=input/10
        index++
    }
    return arr
}
```

The basic idea is to use mod 10 to get the value in a particular digits place and divide by 10 to get to the next digit. Repeat this process until dividing by 10 gives you zero, as this is when you have reached the end of your number. Floor(log(input)/log(10)) + 1 is a trick to find out how many digits a number possesses.