# How to read from keyboard a variable number of integers in C++?

Tags: c++, cin

I need to read a variable number of integers from keyboard so that I can use each of them.

First I thought I could use something like

```
    int myinteger;
    for (int i=0; i<MAX_NUMBER_OF_INTEGERS; i++){
    cin >> myinteger;
    //What I want to do with that Integer
    }
```

But then I realized that if MAX_NUMBERS_OF_INTEGERS = 10 I have to write 10 integers. But what I want is that I can pass "1 2 3" "1 2 3 4" (for example) and not necessary write 10 integers.

Comment: The IMHO most simple way would be to define a value as end of input marker. May be, something like "Enter -1 to finish" assuming that -1 is not a valid integer concerning your problem. Alternatively, you could read integers until input fails e.g. `for (int value; cin >> value;) { /* store value */ }`.

Comment: You could use while (cin >> myinteger) { // do something with myinteger } and have the user press `ctrl-d` on linux or `ctrl-z` on windows to end the input.

Comment: Thank you both but I think that wouldn't works for me since that the "user" is a online judge that check if my program works and ouput the right results

Comment: @Uwunt then you have to modify your question to say exactly what you want. All 3 of us thought that you did not want the fixed maximum so we gave you ways to allow for the user to enter as many numbers as they wanted and signal that they were finished.

Comment: You are rigth, sorry. Edited

Comment: @Uwunt To be honest it is still very unclear. Where to you want to pass the max number? As a function parameter or do you want the user to inout the max number via the input ? With my solution you can abort the inout by typing a non digit character. So you don't have to write as much as MAX value. If this is not what you want you have to be more precise

Comment: Sorry for explaining so bad. Suppose `int MAX = 10` I want the program to do something like `cin >> integer1 >> integer2 >> `..etc..  until `>>integer10;` but that can also accept 1,2,3....9 integers instead of 10. So the user can write "1 2" "1 2 3" ..... "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9" and still works but dont works then "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11"

Comment: Online judges usually input the number of items before they input the items. The question usually states this.

Comment: @drescherjm Yes you are right but this time nope. It just says the maximum number of integers that can be passed from keyboard

Comment: Maybe they are entering all numbers on a single line and expect you to use std::getline(). If this is not the case (and the other solutions don't work) I don't know the answer.

Comment: Yes they are entering all numbers on a single line, so how could I use getline in this case? @drescherjm

Comment: https://ideone.com/HyoWlb

Comment: And how I state the limit of input numbers? @drescherjm

Comment: @Uwunt see my updated answer

Comment: Rolled back - as this question my be useful to other readers in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question seems to have changed a little bit since it was asked and a good answer was given. This just serves to answer the new questions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

const int MAX_NUMBERS_OF_INTEGERS = 10;

int main() {
    std::string line;
    std::cout << "Enter at most " << MAX_NUMBERS_OF_INTEGERS << " ints, separated by spaces: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, line);

    // create a string stream of the line you entered
    std::stringstream ss(line);

    // create a container for storing the ints
    std::vector<int> myInts;

    // a temporary to extract ints from the string stream
    int myInteger;

    // extract at most MAX_NUMBERS_OF_INTEGERS ints from the string stream
    // and store them in the container
    while(myInts.size()<MAX_NUMBERS_OF_INTEGERS && ss>>myInteger) myInts.push_back(myInteger);

    std::cout << "Extracted " << myInts.size() << " integer(s)\n";

    // loop through the container and print all extracted ints.
    for(int i : myInts) {
        std::cout << i << "\n";
    }
    // ... or access a certain int by index
    if(myInts.size() > 2)
        std::cout << "The third int was: " << myInts[2] << "\n";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
std::vector<int> read_ints;
int _temp;
for(;;)
{        
    cin >>_temp;
    if(!cin.good()) {
        break;
    }
    else {
        read_ints.push_back(_temp);
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this solution but it should read an arbitrary number of ints from cin until you enter something else than an integer. You could also skip the saving in the vector part if you don't need to save the results. This is just releveant if you want to save an arbitray number of integers.

EDIT: After clarification your solution could look like this:

```
 int MAX_CHARS = 10;
 int my_int;
 cin >> setw(MAX_CHARS) >> my_int;
```

setw limits the number of input characters but you have to include iomanip header

If you want to access every digit, convert int to vector of ints with this function:

```
vector <int> integerToArray(int x)
{
    vector <int> resultArray;
    while (true)
    {
        resultArray.insert(resultArray.begin(), x%10);
        x /= 10;
        if(x == 0)
            return resultArray;
    }
 }
```

then you can access each digit with the index e.g. first digit

```
 vectory<int> resultArray = integerToArray(my_int);
 int digit = resultArray[0];
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45590971/5529396)

Comment: I think that doesn't work for me since that my program should be able to read 3 numbers, 5 numbers, .... with a MAX defined and do an operation with each of them

Comment: I thought your goal was to not specify a MAX value ? At least thats what I read from your question. If not please clarify what your specific goal is.

Comment: This looks nice, just one question. How can I use each number entered?

Comment: @Uwunt Updated again

Answer (score 1):

One way to read all numbers from a single line limiting them to a maximum number of integers is using std::getline() to get the line into a string then use istringstream in a loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::string line; 
    std::getline (std::cin,line); 
    std::istringstream iss(line);

    int myInt;

    for(int i=0;(iss >> myInt) && (i < MAX_NUMBER_OF_INTEGERS);++i ) {
        std::cout << myInt << ' ';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note: I did not define `MAX_NUMBER_OF_INTEGERS` in the code. I could have defined it with `const int MAX_NUMBERS_OF_INTEGERS = 10;` before usage or possibly that could be a preprocessor define or even a command line parameter. I leave this up to the user.